# "Unsatisfied native code filter" error when trying to export OSGi fragment in Eclipse with custom vm arg

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox, osgi-fragment

There seems to be only one other question of this nature, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240627/unsatisfied-native-code-filter-when-exporting-osgi-bundle-containing-native-an), but the solution suggested by that answer hasn't been effective for me. I am using Spring Tool Suite (essentially Kepler 4.3.2 SR2) as my IDE to develop an OSGi fragment that contains the latest version of some native C++ code. The fragments exist to allow for the possibility of different version of software existing in different environments that this native code is intended to integrate with.

However I am unable to export this fragment, apparently on account of a custom vm arg that we use to represent this version number.

The manifest looks something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Windows 64-bit support for Third-Party XYZ 4.12.7
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.ourcompany.oursoftwarepackage.xyz.win64xyz4127  
Bundle-Version: 8.6.2.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: OurCompany
Fragment-Host: com.ourcompany.oursoftwarepackage.xyz
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86_64))
Bundle-NativeCode: xyzintegration.dll; selection-filter = "(oursoftwarepackage.xyzVersion=4.12.7)"
Bundle-ClassPath: .
```

The error says:

> Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.pde.container.feature:
>   Bundle
>   com.ourcompany.oursoftwarepackage.xyz.win64xyz4127_8.6.2.qualifier
>   failed to resolve.:   Unsatisfied native code filter:
>   xyzintegration.dll;
>   selection-filter="(oursoftwarepackage.xyzVersion=4.12.7)".

If I remove the selection filter clause then it appears to export but there is no actual artifact produced.

The suggestion I extrapolated from the link above was to include the vmarg

```
-Doursoftwarepackage.xyzVersion=4.12.7
```

in the plug-in development target environment. That, however, did not appear to satisfy the OSGi framework. Now I am at a loss as to how to get the fragment to resolve so that the export can proceed.

Comment: You say that you added the vmarg in your PDE target environment. What does that mean? Are you using this vmarg on starting your application?

Comment: In the target environment there is a setting for vmargs. I added the custom arg there.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you talk about the target environment setting of the target definition editor. At least that is the only place I know for such a setting. But that is the definition of the target you are developing against. It does not specify the runtime.

You need to set the VM parameter in the Run configuration.

Run -> Run Configurations... -> Select the application to start -> Switch to the Arguments tab -> insert the value to the VM arguments section